# C# label text property not changing on event

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to change `lbl_smallBlind.Text` and `lbl_bigBlind.Text` to values retrieved from database. Can somebody tell me why it's not working?

---The code that, I think, accessess labels' properties:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public string lbl_sb_text
    {
        get { return lbl_smallBlind.Text; }
        set { lbl_smallBlind.Text = value; }
    }

    public string lbl_bb_text
    {
        get { return lbl_bigBlind.Text; }
        set { lbl_bigBlind.Text = value; }
    }
}
```

---- The code that retrieves values from DB:

```
public void rozne()
{

    string constr = Properties.Settings.Default.DodgeBulletsDBConnectionString;
    Form1 menuglowne = new Form1();

    using (SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection(constr))
    {
        SqlCeCommand com = new SqlCeCommand(
            "SELECT Big_blind, Small_blind FROM Site WHERE Level=1", con);
        con.Open();
        SqlCeDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();

        bool hasRow = reader.Read();
        if (hasRow)
        {
            int bb = reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("Big_blind"));
            int sb = reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("Small_blind"));
            menuglowne.lbl_sb_text = Convert.ToString(sb);
            menuglowne.lbl_bb_text = Convert.ToString(bb);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Coś się zjebało z importem DS.Site.");
        }
    }
}
```

The `lbl_sb_text` and `lbl_bb_text` values are set to what I want, just the values on the form do not change. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need not create Form1 instance again. Since it will initialize all the components for seperate object

```
public void rozne()
{

    string constr = Properties.Settings.Default.DodgeBulletsDBConnectionString;
    //Form1 menuglowne = new Form1();

    using (SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection(constr))
    {
        SqlCeCommand com = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT Big_blind, Small_blind FROM Site WHERE Level=1", con);
        con.Open();
        SqlCeDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();

        bool hasRow = reader.Read();
        if (hasRow)
        {
            int bb = reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("Big_blind"));
            int sb = reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("Small_blind"));
            this.lbl_sb_text = Convert.ToString(sb);
            this.lbl_bb_text = Convert.ToString(bb);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Coś się zjebało z importem DS.Site.");
        }
    }
}
```

**Here are my suggestions**

```
//Form1 menuglowne = new Form1();
this.lbl_sb_text = Convert.ToString(sb);
this.lbl_bb_text = Convert.ToString(bb);
```